# How to import src for a script in index.html file

Tags: javascript, html

Currently in my `index.html` file I have the following script line:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
```

Is it possible to extract the `src` variable and import it in the script as a variable? I tried using `xsl:variable` located in an external `variable.xsl` file such as this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:variable name="google" select="API_KEY"></xsl:variable>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And then trying to import it into my script,

```
<xsl:include href="variable.xsl"/>
<script src="{$google}"></script>
```

But even when the `xls:variable` is in the same file, the script source doesn't work.

I would like to push my code to a public repo, which is why I'd like to hide the key.

Comment: You changed the title just now.. Is your goal still to hide the key? You don't really have to.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using XSL? You don't have that in your tags, so it's a bit confusing to see it in the question. As far as getting a parameter from a url, there's [get javascript url parameter from script source file in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21424880/215552).

Comment: @HereticMonkey no real reason as to why I am using XSL. Just something I was trying, willing to try anything else.

Comment: @LucaKiebel Yes, my goal is to hide the key, but thought that I can get a more generic title

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get javascript url parameter from script source file in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21424880/get-javascript-url-parameter-from-script-source-file-in-html)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729976/does-google-maps-javascript-api-key-v3-need-to-be-kept-secret-in-html-checked <- not really a dupe though

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is the answer you are looking for, by simply using JQuery you could add the `src` attribute dynamically

**HTML**

```html
<script id="googleAPI">
```

*Notice we set an id on the script element*

**Javascript**

```
let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&libraries=places"
$("#googleAPI").attr("src", url)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot hide something client side, only obfustucate it (make it harder to see). If you use the xsl file, I can make a request and see that, if you set the dynamically create the script, I can open the network tab see where the request is going. If you want to hide the key:

- make a request from your own server to `"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&libraries=places"`
- get the content as `text/plain` or convert it to `dataURl` and then send it to client side where you create a `script` tag and set the `textContent`, `innerHTML`, or create an object url from `Blob` (having the server response as `Blob` part) and set src etc.